# EWS Managed API to manage ( Add/Remove/Get ) MailboxPermissions

Tags: ews-managed-api

Can EWS Managed API be used to administer Mail Box Permissions in Exchange 2010 Online Environment? Specifically Get-MailboxPermission Add-MailboxPermission Remove-MailboxPermission Add-ReceipientPermission Remove-RecipientPermission

Answer (score 1):

Mailbox permission are like folder permission and this should be possible. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb856574%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx